# Ms Access Error - The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2013

I am trying to build a select query in ms access, however am getting the error message: "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add."

The sql is :

```
SELECT ProjectList.ProjectID, UpcomingOpenMilestone.MinOfPlannedDate, 
UpcomingOpenMilestone.FirstOfMilestone
FROM UpcomingOpenMilestone RIGHT JOIN ProjectList ON 
UpcomingOpenMilestone.ProjectID = ProjectList.ProjectID;
```

The query is pulling from one other query and a table. The ProjectList.ProjectID field is an autonumber field.

The `UpcomingOpenMilestone` qry is generated from one table and the sql is as follows:

```
SELECT MilestoneTracking.ProjectID, Min(MilestoneTracking.PlannedDate) AS 
MinOfPlannedDate, First(MilestoneTracking.Milestone) AS FirstOfMilestone
FROM MilestoneTracking
GROUP BY MilestoneTracking.ProjectID, MilestoneTracking.ActualDate
HAVING (((MilestoneTracking.ActualDate) Is Null));
```

The ProjectID is the foreign key, therefore number type field, Milestone is a short text and limited to 200 characters and then PlannedDate and ActualDate are both date type fields.

I don't understand why the field would be too small, I've tried limiting the query that is generating the error to only try and pull in the ProjectID or other single fields however it does not work. The only way that it will run is if I drop the `Right Join`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not the answer, but for UpcomingOpenMilestone,  replace the `HAVING` by `WHERE`.

Comment: Are you trying to l ink this query to a combo box?

Comment: No, not trying to link to any fields/combo boxes on a form @random_answer_guy

Comment: @iDevlop after changing it to where it did end up working, thanks!